# Why is setAttribute faster than property assignment for transform matrix in SVG?

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, properties

I have created this test here:
[JS Performance test](https://jsperf.com/svgelemdraggingapproach2)

I am comparing:  setAttribute vs property assignment for svg transform translate matrix in there.

I thought that setAttribute will perform slower because it basically deals with strings for matrix data, while with direct modification of transform I thought we are "going" direct.

Is that caching that makes this so much faster?

Comment: dom lookups are slow, and your property mutator uses several dom dots in the path. if you cached the `subject.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.` part it should be a lot faster.

Comment: ahhh checking this now;) ty

Comment: Yup, I told you!  ;) about 8X better. good times.

Comment: You are right its just WAY faster.

Comment: I don't think the super cached version is valid as you're not updating the DOM any more at that point.

Comment: yes sorry I added it more to see what is the speed with primmitives. But you are right its misleadiing..